# Identifying a connector

Tags: connector, cnc, crimp

Can anyone identify this connector?

Female part:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

The crimp parts look like this:

[image]

And the male part looks like this:

[image]

Context:

These came with a Smoothieboard v1.1. I keep messing up the crimp connections, so I want to order some spare connectors. The documentation does not seems to identify them. If there's any sort of site that has a directory of connector types, that would be good to know too.

Comment: What is the pitch?

Comment: Try molex is my advice.

Comment: are you using a crimp tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a “Molex” 4-position connector. It seems to be part connector series “2695” (if you look up ‘Molex 2695’, you get plenty of results). If you go to Molex’s page directly for that part, they even provide a nice “Mates with/use with” section detailing the corresponding headers / crimps / pre-crimped leads).

Here is a link for what I think you want:

[Molex 4-Position female connector](https://www.molex.com/molex/products/part-detail/crimp_housings/0022012041)

Comment: This appear to be it - thank you. I'll order some and confirm whether they work.

Comment: They arrived, are indeed the correct connectors.

Answer (score 2):

Molex "KK" series, I believe -- [link](https://www.molex.com/molex/products/family/kk_254_rpc_connector_system)